# TabBar app - load data before showing view

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I am making an app based on tabBar menu at the bottom. The initial view is a simple view with button, textfields, labels and so forth.
The second tab/view is a tableView where the data for the cells are retrieve from a server in appDelegate when app starts. But if the user presses the second tab before the data is downloaded, well then then tableView is empty.

How can i ensure that the user can not press the second tab before the data for tableView has been downloaded?
Or must I show a temporary view with a spinner or something like that?

Please note that I am using storyboards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should comment, but I lack the reputation. This has been asked and answered before:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13613796/3071962

In a nutshell: `[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:2]setEnabled:FALSE];`
and, once the download finished

`[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:2]setEnabled:TRUE];`

Answer (score 0):

You can set simply:

Disable userInteraction when data are still downloaded

```
UITabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

... when data was downloaded turn the userInteraction on

```
UITabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```